# Two sided BFS correctness

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithm, breadth-first-search

A [bi-directional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_search) search / two-say BFS has a faster look up time as compared to a single-ended BFS.

A bi-directional search, works as follows

> Do a traditional BFS from either ends, and save the visited nodes in
>   their respective Queues. If a node is common, between the two queues,
>   we can conclude that a path exists.

However, say, I am asked to find a path between `node1` and `node2` in the graph below, this algorith would report that a path exists, and 1 to be the distance between the nodes, since node3 is common to both queues.

```
node1 -> node3 <- node2
```

However, this is not true, and is an incorrect result. Is a bi-directional search expected to work for directed graphs, or is there an alteration to my approach required?

This is my code below

```
public int searchDoubleEndedBfs( GraphNode node1, GraphNode node2 )
    {
        Queue<GraphNode> headQueue = new LinkedList<>();
        Set<GraphNode> visited = new HashSet<>();
        Queue<GraphNode> tailQueue = new LinkedList<>();
        Queue<GraphNode> childQueue = new LinkedList<>();
        int count = 0;

        headQueue.add(node1);
        visited.add(node1);
        tailQueue.add(node2);
        visited.add(node2);

        while(headQueue.size() > 0 && tailQueue.size() > 0)
        {
            if(headQueue.size() > tailQueue.size())
            {
                Queue<GraphNode> temp = new LinkedList<>();
                temp = headQueue;
                headQueue = tailQueue;
                tailQueue = temp;
            }

            GraphNode node = headQueue.poll();
            for(int i = 0;i<node.neighbors.size();i++)
            {
                GraphNode neighbor = node.neighbors.get(i);

                if(tailQueue.contains(neighbor))
                    return count+1;

                if(!visited.contains(neighbor))
                {
                    childQueue.add(neighbor);
                    visited.add(neighbor);
                }
            }

            headQueue.addAll(childQueue);
            childQueue.clear();
            count++;
        }

        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: At glance, I can tell you that the problem is in your approach. There is nothing to prevent you from doing this in directed graphs.You might look at this paper  (https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~krste/papers/beamer-sc2012.pdf) and see their approach.

Comment: Naturally, you need to reverse the direction of the edges when searching backwards.

Answer (score 0):

Starting on this line:

GraphNode node = headQueue.poll();

Instead of polling just 1 node out of headQueue, you should be going through all the nodes in headQueue. Essentially all nodes for each level should all be pulled out in order to have correct level count.